# multiple Onload functions not working in Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, onload

Here is my code
`<body scroll="yes" onload="checkWhileOnload(#{Bean.conLimit},'#{Bean.URL}');checkLoadStatus();hideLoader();">`

The problem i m facing is the function checkLoadStatus() is not at all invoked in Safari and Chrome where as it is working fine in IE and FF. can some one please help me on this?

Comment: What does the actual code look like after the server tags are processed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try separating your js code from your html.

```
window.onload = function(){
    checkWhileOnload(#{Bean.conLimit},'#{Bean.URL}');
    checkLoadStatus();
    hideLoader();
}
```

I'm not sure about your quotes, you should look into that

Comment: I used Javascrip console to find out the error and the problem is with 

`document.getElementById('reportMetaDatImg').click();`

Chrome  says 
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an HTMLImageElement> has no method 'click'

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: @Tinkerbel  - are you using jQuery? Also, that is a section of your code that you haven't put up here. I can't help you much with that

Comment: No- I am not using jQuery. My checkLoadStatus() in turn invokes other functions and it is being struck with the click().

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add a quotes

```
window.onload = function(){
checkWhileOnload('#{Bean.conLimit}','#{Bean.URL}');
checkLoadStatus();
hideLoader();
}
```

What does the javascript console console say (Ctrl+Shift+J)

Comment: from Javascript console i found out that document.getElementById('DatImg').click(); is throwing error. When i comment this my code is working fine. The problem is Chrome says there

Comment: you could try document.getElementById("DatImg").onclick = function() {} or document.getElementById("DatImg").addEventListener("click",function(){});

Answer (score 0):

Its just a place problem see this:,
window.onload = function(){ 
checkLoadStatus();
checkWhileOnload('#{Bean.conLimit}','#{Bean.URL}');
hideLoader();
}

Place your checkload status first; can u do that.:(

Comment: No, I cant do that. It must be only in the given order.